# Using jupyter_nbextensions_configurator in Google colab

Tags: python, python-3.x, jupyter-notebook, ipython, google-colaboratory

I am trying to use **jupyter_nbextensions_configurator** in google colab and execute following commands in succession:

```
!pip install https://github.com/ipython-contrib/jupyter_contrib_nbextensions/tarball/master
!jupyter contrib nbextension install --user
!jupyter nbextensions_configurator enable --user
!jupyter nbextension enable execute_time/ExecuteTime
```

The last command results in the output:

[image]

However, after this when I execute the next cell, it doesn't show the last executed time or the length of time it took to execute it.

Is there any specific step that I am missing?